# How do I express this $f(x,y)$ in terms of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers

$$f(x,y)=e^y\sin x+ie^y\cos x$$

The problem requires me to express in terms of $z$ only.

**My attempt:**

$$=e^y(\sin x+i\cos x)$$

$$=ie^y(\cos x-i\sin x)$$

If $e^{-i\theta}=(\cos\theta - i\sin \theta)$, then:

$$=ie^ye^{-i\theta}$$

But then I get stuck. I'm not sure what to do with the $e^y$.

**Note:** - the final answer is given. It says it's:

$$f(z)=ie^{-iz}+c$$

...but I still need to learn how to arrive at that answer.

Comment: I think you can define $z$ as complex number.

Comment: Hint: That's $x$ not $\theta$.  Hint 2: $ie^ye^{-ix} = ie^{(y-ix)}$

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhh thanks @GrahamKemp!!! Oh geez....

Comment: Small note: use `\sin x` to show $\sin x$. This works for common functions, like the trig functions :)

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$\begin{align}
e^y(\sin(x)+i\cos(x))&=i(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))e^y\\\\
&=e^{-ix+y+i\pi/2}\\\\
&=e^{-i(x+iy-\pi/2)}\\\\
&=e^{-i(z-\pi/2)}
\end{align}$$